# Wanna watch basketball competitions

Tags: basketball, training, match-identification

To people who are intersted in watching basketball matches I'm a beginner in training basketball and I wanna watch competitions to have more experience from watching
Suggest me your favourite team and when will be the next match✋..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## The best basketball games to watch would be from the NBA Summer League and the WNBA Season.

The NBA Summer League starts on Friday, July fifth. One good team to watch in the Summer League would be the Memphis Grizzlies. They recently acquired Ja Morant in the draft, and paired with young forward Jaren Jackson Jr., they could make an interesting pair to watch. Also, another team to watch would be the New Orleans Pelicans. The New Orleans Pelicans recently drafted Zion Williamson, a very good player to watch.
[Here is the complete schedule](https://www.nba.com/article/2019/06/21/2019-nba-summer-league-schedule-official-release)

The other thing to watch would be the WNBA. This year, the top five teams are the Connecticut Sun, the Washington Mystics, the Chicago Sky, the Seattle Storm, and the Las Vegas Aces. These would be the ideal teams to watch play.
[Here is the complete WNBA schedule.](https://www.wnba.com/schedule/)
Under the time of the game, it will say how you can watch it.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this, could you please tell me so I can improve it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, idk why they dis vote that but I like your answer♥

Comment: Thank you very much... I hope you have a good time watching basketball. Also, the NBA will reboot in October this year, so you can watch it then